# How to Enhance the Voice Recognition on Raspberry Pi controlling Smart Home Devices

Tags: smart-home, raspberry-pi, voice-recognition

I have a Raspberry Pi running [Jarvis](https://github.com/alexylem/jarvis), a personal IA that I can use with my voice to control my smart home devices.

However, the voice recognition is far from perfect. They have a [list of speech-to-text (STT) services](http://domotiquefacile.fr/jarvis/content/stt) that I could use.

Should I be worried about privacy if a choose a better service?
What can I do to improve the current service I use? Is buying a better microphone a good idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try [Raspberry Pi with .NET Core](https://www.hackster.io/krvarma/rpivoice-051857). Microsoft has published decent automation libraries, including speech recognition. This is of course more hands-on, but combine it with other sensors and software, and you could do some pretty cool stuff.

Microsoft also utilize their speech recognition libraries in their Bing APIs, so you could potentially use the web service to drive your project. This then relies on basic internet security through authorization and other basic security protocols.